# Which between Underscore methods or Backbone methods are faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, backbone.js, underscore.js

I use both underscore methods and backbone methods. I want to know which among them performs better and faster? I am trying for collection with large sets of data and the number of collection is also more.

Example:

```
_.filter(collection, predicate);
collection.filter(predicate);
```

Comment: This is not a good question for SO. Write two or more pieces of code and measure them yourself if you want to know which one is faster.

Comment: I disagree with @Tomalak's assessment; I think it's a perfectly reasonable question that others may be wondering.

Comment: @CullenJ No, that's not how it works. An idle *"I wonder which is faster"* with no code to accompany it and no reasoning is an indication that a) the OP just wants someone to write it for them and doesn't really care about the performance and b) the OP has not spent any of their own time on the issue, otherwise they would have something to show and c) without any context (library versions, JS runtime, test fixture) it does not matter which of a specific implementation is faster at this point in time. It's neither transferable to another setup nor can you rely on it one month from now.

Answer (score 3):

This is [how backbone adds `_` methods](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/bd50e2e4a4af5c09bc490185aab215794d42258b/backbone.js#L99-L103) to it's built in Constructors:

```
var addUnderscoreMethods = function(Class, methods, attribute) {
  _.each(methods, function(length, method) {
     if (_[method]) Class.prototype[method] = addMethod(length, method, attribute);
  });
};
```

[`addMethod`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/bd50e2e4a4af5c09bc490185aab215794d42258b/backbone.js#L78-L98) returns a function like this:

```
return function(value) {
  return _[method](this[attribute], value);
};
```

So simply put it's  just different ways of invoking the same method.

From a pure performance perspective, invoking the `_` method directly is likely to be tiny little bit faster by avoiding the wrapper function invokation.

From a readability and maintenance perspective, the collection methods will be better. The performance difference will be insignificant in reasonable sized collections on modern browsers. Which is why they are available in the first place.